# Randomly sample rows based on year-month

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series

```
data = {'date':['2019-01-01', '2019-01-02', '2020-01-01', '2020-02-02'],
        'tweets':["aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd"]}

df = pandas.DataFrame(data)

df['daate'] = pandas.to_datetime(df['date'], infer_datetime_format=True)
```

So I have an object type date and a datetime64[ns] type date. Image that I have 100 rows in each year-month. How can I randomly sample 10 rows in each year-month and put them into a data frame? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) per years and months or month periods and use custom lambda function with [`DataFrame.sample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html):

```
df1 = (df.groupby([df['daate'].dt.year, df['daate'].dt.month], group_keys=False)
         .apply(lambda x: x.sample(n=10)))
```

Or:

```
df1 = (df.groupby(df['daate'].dt.to_period('m'), group_keys=False)
         .apply(lambda x: x.sample(n=10)))
```

**Sample**:

```
data = {'daate':pd.date_range('2019-01-01', '2020-01-22'),
        'tweets':np.random.choice(["aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd"], 387)
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)


df1 = (df.groupby([df['daate'].dt.year, df['daate'].dt.month], group_keys=False)
         .apply(lambda x: x.sample(n=10)))
print (df1)
          date tweets      daate
9   2019-01-10    bbb 2019-01-10
29  2019-01-30    ddd 2019-01-30
17  2019-01-18    ccc 2019-01-18
12  2019-01-13    ccc 2019-01-13
20  2019-01-21    ddd 2019-01-21
..         ...    ...        ...
381 2020-01-17    bbb 2020-01-17
375 2020-01-11    aaa 2020-01-11
373 2020-01-09    bbb 2020-01-09
368 2020-01-04    aaa 2020-01-04
382 2020-01-18    bbb 2020-01-18

[130 rows x 3 columns]
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {"date": ["2019-01-01", "2019-01-02", "2020-01-01", "2020-02-02"], "tweets": ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df["daate"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"], infer_datetime_format=True)

# Just duplicating row
df = df.loc[df.index.repeat(100)]

# The actual code
available_dates = df["daate"].unique()
sampled_df = pd.DataFrame()
for each_date in available_dates:
    rows_with_that_date = df.loc[df["daate"] == each_date]
    sampled_rows_with_that_date = rows_with_that_date.sample(5)  # 5 samples
    sampled_df = sampled_df.append(sampled_rows_with_that_date)

print(len(sampled_df))
```